# How ro pass an List/array from javascript controller to helper

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, list, parameters, array

I have the following attribute in my lightning component

```
<aura:attribute name="serverList" type="Opleiding__c[]"/>
```

I can call this in my javascript controller with

```
var serverList = component.get("v.serverList");
```

I want to be able to pass its value to my javascript helper

I tried in my helper

```
({
selectedTrue : function(serverList) {..}
})
```

or

```
    ({
        selectedTrue : function(serverList){
var serverList = component.get("v.serverList");}
    })
```

Both do not work, am i missing something?

Comment: What you've written should work; what problem are you experiencing? An error? An exception?

Comment: @sfdcfox    Everything in the code after this line does not work anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<aura:attribute name="serverList" type="Opleiding__c[]"/>
```

> Your component controller should look like:

```
someFunction: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.helperMethod(component, component.get("v.serverList") );
}
```

> Your component helper should look like:

```
helperMethod : function(component, Servers) {
    console.log('Server List********', Servers);
}
```

I have the same logic working but i pass accounts from component to helper like above. 
You were missing `component` in below statement

```
({
    selectedTrue : function(serverList) {
        var serverList = component.get("v.serverList");
    }
})
```

Hope the solution helps!!